# Using RegEx in VB.Net to extract Download Link

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a Webpage which can contain the following href format.

```
<a href='/documents/aso2v51_1bk.pdf' target="_blank">Ordering Model – Access Service Volume II – Analysis</a>
```

the page can contain 0 or more of these type of links. I would like to extract the href path and the Title of the doc. I want to avoid doing this in vb.net via split and hope there is a simple fix in RegEx

Comment: In the end , the simplest fix is to use an HTML parser like [HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/846994/1115360).

Comment: You may use the following expression: `(?<=href=)(?<href>.*')(?:.*?(?=>)>)(?<title>.*(?=<))` . Live regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/S1F1fJ/2). The two capture groups are named `href` and `title` respectively. Does this help?

Comment: Yes that does it pretty much, i made some smaller change so it looks like this now (?<=href='\/documents\/)(?<href>.*')(?:.*?(?=>)>)(?<title>.*(?=<)) my question how can i eliminate the " ' " at the end of the href part in regEx

Comment: @MisterniceGuy I've updated my answer with your new requirements, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
(?<=href='\/documents\/)(?<href>.*(?='))(?:.*?(?=>)>)(?<title>.*(?=<))
```

- `(?<=href='\/documents\/)` Positive lookbehind.
- `(?<href>.*(?='))` Named capture group, match everything up to the " ' " .
- `(?:.*?(?=>)>)` Match but don't capture everything up to " > ".
- `(?<title>.*(?=<))` Named capture group, match everything up to " < ".

Live regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/S1F1fJ/3).

*Group href* : `aso2v51_1bk.pdf`

*Group title* : `Ordering Model – Access Service Volume II – Analysis`